# Find the last $4$ digits of $2016^{2016}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the last $4$ digits of $2016^{2016}$.

Technically I was able to solve this question by I used Wolfram Alpha and modular arithmetic so the worst I had to do was raise a $4$ digit number to the $9$th power. I would do $2016^2 \equiv 4256^2 \equiv \cdots$
 and then continue using the prime factorization of $2016$. I am wondering if there is a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 6):

$$\begin{align}(2000+16)^{2016}&\equiv 2016\cdot 2000\cdot 16^{2015} + 16^{2016}&\pmod{10000}\\
&\equiv 2000+16^{2016}&\pmod{10000}
\end{align}$$

So you need to find the last four digits of $16^{2016}$ and add $2000$.

You can actually reduce the exponent modulo $500$, because $16^{2016}\equiv 16^{16}\pmod{625}$ and $16^{2016}\equiv 0\equiv 16^{16}\pmod{16}$.

So you need to compute $16^{16}\mod{10000}$. This can be done by repeated squaring:

$$16^2=256\\
16^4=256^2\equiv 5536\pmod{10000}\\
16^8\equiv 5536^2\equiv 7296\pmod{10000}\\
16^{16}\equiv 7276^2\equiv 1616\pmod{10000}\\
$$

So the result is $2000+1616=3616$.

Comment: You should mention you used Euler's theorem.

Comment: Don't you mean $(2000+16)^{2016} \equiv \cdot 2000\cdot 16^{2015} + 16^{2016} \pmod{10000}$?

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. @Puzzled417 $(16+x)^n = 16^n + n\cdot 16^{n-1}\cdot x + \cdots$. You need that factor of $n$. It doesn't have any effect here, so it gets the same result (since $6^k\equiv 6\pmod {10}$, so the term will be $\equiv 2000\cdot 6\pmod{10^4}$ whether we include that term or not.)

Comment: i also used the binomial theorem. I decided not to spell things out. @user236182

Comment: Why are you multiplying by $2016$?

Comment: Do you know the binomial theorem? What is the second term of $(x+y)^n$? Hint: It has a factor of $n$. Now, apply to $x=16,y=2000,n=2016$. @Puzzled417

Comment: The second term of that is $\binom{n}{1} x*y^{n-1}$.

Comment: And what is $\binom{n}{1}$? @Puzzled417

Comment: Oh, I see now thanks.

Comment: Anyone else think they should have asked: "what are the last *two* digits of 2016^20**16**"?

Answer (score 3):

You can afford to work modulo $16=2^4$ and modulo $625=5^4$ separately. The basis $2016$ is a multiple of $16$ and therefore so are all its powers.

We also know that $2016\equiv141$ modulo $625.$

To take the $2016$-th power note that $141$ is invertible modulo $625$ (because it is relatively prime with $5$) and therefore its $500$-th power is equivalent to $1$ modulo $625$ (the multiplicative group modulo $625$ has order $5^3.(5-1)=500$). Thus we can limit ourselves to the $16$-th power.

To evaluate $141^{16}$ modulo $625$ notice that $141=5^3+16$ so

$$\eqalign{141^{16}=\sum_{i=0}^{16}{16\choose i}5^{3i}16^{16-i}
&\equiv16^{16}+16.16^{15}.125\\
&\equiv16^{16}+1.125\\
16^{16}=(3.5+1)^{16}=\sum_{i=0}^{16}{16\choose i}3^i5^i
&\equiv 1+16.3.5+8.15.3^2.5^2+8.5.14.3^3.5^3\\
&\equiv1+48.5+216.125\\
&\equiv1+48.5+1.125=366\\
141^{16}&\equiv366+125=491\\
}$$

This means we are looking for a number between $0$ and $9999$ that is a multiple of $16$ and that is $491$ more than a multiple of $625.$ Since $625\equiv1$ and $491\equiv11$ modulo 16 the solution should be $(16-11).625+491=3616.$

Comment: I think that you mean 625=$5^4$. After all, the question is asking for the last 4 digits.

Comment: Should be modulo $2^4=16$ and $5^4=625$.

Comment: Corrected, thanks to you both.

Answer (score 3):

Since $2016$ is a multiple of $16$, we shall look at the $2016^ {2016}$ modular $625$.

Well, following from [Euler`s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), $2016^{2016} \equiv 2016^{16} \pmod {625}$. Note that $2016^ {15}=(2000+16)^ {15} \equiv16^ {15} \pmod {625}$, following from the [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). However, $16^ {15}=2^ {60} \equiv 399^6 \equiv (400-1)^6$, which calculated through the binomial theorem, is $101$. This gives us that $2016^ {16} \equiv 101*2016 \equiv 491 \pmod {625}$.

Combining this with the upper result gives us $3616$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Allow me give a different answer from the three ones above and easy to achieve with a calculator, please. This direct procedure can be applied to similar calculations.

One can simply use one or both properties, $A^{abc}=(A^a)^{bc}\equiv(B)^{bc}\pmod{M}$   and $A^n=A^r\cdot A^s\equiv(B)\cdot (C)\pmod{M}$   where $r+s=n$, iterating the process according to convenience of exponents.$$******$$

$2016^{2016}=(2^5\cdot3^2\cdot7)^{2016}=(2^{2^5\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot7})(3^{2^6\cdot3^2\cdot7})(7^{2^5\cdot3^2\cdot7})$

Calculating separately each of the three factors, we have

$2^{2^5\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot7}\equiv(8368)^{6\cdot6\cdot 8}\equiv (9024)^{6\cdot 8}\equiv (8976)^8\equiv6176\pmod{ 10^4} $

$3^{2^6\cdot3^2\cdot7}\equiv(3203)^{8\cdot8\cdot3}\equiv(3761)^{8\cdot3}\equiv(8881)^3\equiv1841\pmod{ 10^4} $

$7^{2^5\cdot3^2\cdot7}\equiv(4007)^{4\cdot4\cdot6}\equiv(5649)^{4\cdot4}\equiv(2401)^4\equiv9601\pmod{ 10^4} $
Hence $$2016^{2016}\equiv6176\cdot1841\cdot9601\equiv\color{red}{3616}\pmod{ 10^4} $$