# How to calculate $5^{5^{33}}\bmod{100}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to calculate: $$5^{5^{33}}\bmod{100}$$

I am aware of this [quesiton](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand), but still did not understand how to solve for my example.

I know how to use Euler's theorem, but I do not know how to go around $5^{33}$ and $100$ not being co-prime.

Comment: All powers of 5 from the square onwards are $\equiv 25$, maybe?

Comment: I think in this case, first work out $5^2$, then $5^3$, $5^4$, $5^5$, and so on until you reach $5^{5^{33}}$.  Trust me when I say you'll get there faster than you think.

Comment: I am aware of this, but I should solve this question using Euler's theorem or the Chinese remainder theorem. I am thinking about the answer below using the Chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that $25$ divides the given number. Hence, the only possible residues are $0,25,50,75$. Now, 2 definitely does not divide the given number, and so the possible residues are $25,75$. Now, we can just find out the residue mod $4$. The given number is congruent to $1^{5^{33}}=1\text{mod}~ 4$. Out of $25,75$ only $25$ has residue $1$ mod 4. Hence, the residue of the original number mod $100$ is 25.

The point here is that $100=25 \times 4$, and $(25,4)=1$. Hence, to find the residue mod $100$, just find the residue mod $25$ and mod $4$ and use the Chinese remainder theorem to get a unique solution mod $100$.

Answer (score 0):

As $(5^{n+2},100)=25$ for integer $n\ge0$

let us find $5^n\left(\bmod\dfrac{100}{25}\right)$

As $5\equiv1\pmod4,5^n\equiv1^n\equiv?$

$\implies5^{n+2}\equiv5^2\pmod{4\cdot25}$

Here $n+2=5^{33}$

**Reference** :

[How to find last two digits of $2^{2016}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844558/how-to-find-last-two-digits-of-22016)

[what are the last two digits of $2016^{2017}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031610/what-are-the-last-two-digits-of-20162017)

[Find the last two digits of $3^{45}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679842/find-the-last-two-digits-of-345)

[last two digits of $14^{5532}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385396/last-two-digits-of-145532)